# How do i turn underscrore to find the model in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok i have this in what i have

**user.rb  //user model**

```
OPTION = ['none', 'all', 'partial']
ANOTHER = ['true', 'false', 'neither']
YET_ANOTHER = ['something', 'another']
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
 def my_method(information, name)
   #this is where i need help
   User::OPTIONS
```

**index.html.erb**

```
my_method('information', :option)
my_method('information', :another)
my_method('information', :yet_another)
```

How do i in the my_method view helper grab the correct array so for example if i send in

```
my_method('information', :another)
```

in the my_method view helper i should execute

```
   User::ANOTHER
```

I was thinking i could upcase but how to i execute this ....

I tried this below

```
User::name.upcase
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for #<Class:0x000d001078cd9c8>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do the following.

```
User.const_get(name.to_s.upcase)
```

While this works, make sure you aren't passing user-submitted params into const_get. This would be a security vulnerability, allowing user to essentially execute unintended code. Instead you should simply use a condition.

```
info = case params[:something]
when 'foo'; User::FOO
when 'bar'; User::BAR
end
```

Comment: is there a way to do this if the first part is a string also so if i has --------------  information = "User"

Comment: so basically if the modelname was passed into the method as well as the constant name

Comment: I really don't recommend doing this, but `Object.const_get(model_name).const_get(name.to_s.upcase)` will do that.